# ¿Cúal es la diferencia entre dateTime y now?

Tags: c#

```
var dateTime = new DateTime(2015,1,1);
var now = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(dateTime.Hour); // esta me da una hora a lo loco
```

y

```
Console.WriteLine(now.Hour); // y esta me da la hora actual
```

Entonces, la pregunta es la siguiente:

¿Cúal es la diferencia entre `DateTime` y `now`?

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime.Now` trae un objeto completo del tipo `DateTime` haciendo referencia a ***AHORA***, mientras que `now` que es una instancia de un objeto `DateTime` trae el dato especifico que quieres.

```
var now = new DateTime.Now // hoy {27/12/2016 12:41:33}
var hora = now.Hour; //12
var dia = now.Day //27
var mes = now.Month //12
var year = now.Year // 2016
```

¿Por que `dateTime.Hour` te devuelve una hora a lo "loco"?

Porque simplemente no especificaste al momento de crear el objeto `DateTime`

```
var dt = new DateTime(2016, 12, 27);
var tm = TimeSpan.Parse("12:47:50");
var fullDt = dt + tm;
```

Answer (score 1):

EL now es una instancia de DateTime que queda con la hora actual, en cambio la que cita en primera instancia es una forma de construir el DateTime en donde usted suministra los datos que conforman la fecha que se va a trabajar con esa instancia del DateTime, en si no hay diferencia ambas son instancias del DateTime, pero con diferente fecha

Comment: Entonces practicamente: el now = DateTime.Now lo que hace es crear un objeto de tipo DateTime usando el  .Now, permitiendo asi que ese objeto tendra todos sus atributos inicializados ya con los valores actuales?

Comment: @albertocp05 exactamente, los valores de fecha y hora quedan con la hora actual, mientras que de la otra forma queda con los valores que se haya construido